# How to combine explicit args with variable args in function call

Tags: clojure

In JavaScript, one can do the following:

```
function foo(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
  ...
}

var others = [ 'two', 'three' ];
foo('one', ...others);  // same as foo('one', 'two', 'three')
```

In Clojure, "variable args" can be accepted like so:

```clj
(defn foo [arg1 & others]
  ...)
```

But to pass them in combination with other args, you have to do this:

```clj
(apply foo (concat '("one") others))
```

Which is frankly really ugly. It's also impossible when what you need to do is recur:

```clj
(apply recur (concat '("one") others)) ;; doesn't work
```

Is there a better way to do this? And if not, is there any way at all to accomplish it in the `recur` case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But to pass them in combination with other args, you have to do this:
>   `(apply foo (concat '("one") others))`

You don't *have* to do that: `apply` is also a variadic function that can take arguments *before* the final sequence argument e.g.

```
(apply foo "one" others)
```

You can pass any number of individual arguments before the final sequence argument to `apply`.

```
user=> (defn foo [arg1 & args] (apply println arg1 args))
#'user/foo
user=> (apply foo "one" 2 "three" [4 "five" 6.0])
one 2 three 4 five 6.0
```

To further demonstrate, these calls to `+` are functionally equivalent:

```
(apply + 1 2 [3])
(apply + 1 [2 3])
(apply + [1 2 3])
```

> It's also impossible when what you need to do is recur

[`recur` is a special form](https://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#recur), and `apply` doesn't work with it like it would a typical Clojure function.

> is there any way at all to accomplish it in the `recur` case?

Not with `apply`. You can `recur` with variadic args, but you can't `(apply recur ...)`.

Comment: "You don't have to do that: apply is also a variadic function that can take arguments before the final sequence argument e.g. `(apply foo "one" others)` You can pass any number of individual arguments before the final sequence argument to apply."

But wouldn't `others` in this case be passed as a list, and not have its members "flattened" into the remaining arg slots?

Comment: @brundolf in that case `others` _would_ have its members flattened/spread across the remaining argument positions. `(apply + 1 2 [3 4])` is equivalent to `(apply + 1 [2 3 4])` and `(apply + [1 2 3 4])`.

Comment: Odd. What's the exact algorithm there? Surely it can't be, "flatten every sequence passed to apply"? "Flatten the last argument if it's a sequence", perhaps?

Comment: @brundolf It basically assumes that the last parameter is a list. Any other arguments before it and after the function argument are treated as elements to to `cons`d to the argument list.

Comment: It's perfectly possible with `recur`. Given `(defn f [x & xs] ...)`, there are two variables that need to be passed to any `recur` call: `x` and `xs`. You don't need the `apply`, because the compiler knows exactly which arity is being dispatched to (the current one). Thus: `(defn f [x & xs] (if foo 0, (recur (inc x) (rest xs)))(`

Comment: @Carcigenicate that seems unsettlingly arbitrary, but also convenient and it does appear to work. Thanks.

Comment: @brundolf It makes sense when written out. Basically the non-last arguments are treated as though they're `partial`y applied to the function, then the list that's left is applied to the function. Use it for awhile and the order will make perfect sense.